# Combine two columns from single table in one column

Tags: r, merge

So I have an dataset which looks a bit like this:

```
set0 <- data.frame(A = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B"),
                         B = c("E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"))
```

I need to create a table which counts the results and puts it in a table. Therefore I use :

```
set0 <- table(set0, exclude = c("H", "I"))

result:
#> set0
   B
A   E F G
  A 1 0 0
  B 1 1 0
  C 0 1 1
  D 0 0 1
```

I would like to have column F and G merged into V:

```
   B
A   E V
  A 1 0
  B 1 1
  C 0 2
  D 0 1
```

I also need to merge rows which I managed just fine (I think). I would suspect to use the below as wel as for the columnnames but I keep getting an error: subscript out of bounds (For this I changed the rownames to colnames, same for the given values)

```
set0 <- {set0["A", ] = set0["A", ] + set0["B", ]
         set0[rownames(set0) != "B", ]}
```

So is there any way I can merge the Columns F and G and make change this into V?
Or is there maybe another tool I could use to make a similar table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the values of `B` using `replace` or `ifelse` and then use `table` :

```
table(transform(set0, B = replace(B, B %in% c('F', 'G'), 'V')), exclude = c("H", "I"))

#  B
#A   E V
#  A 1 0
#  B 1 1
#  C 0 2
#  D 0 1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks! I know it is not mentioned in my question, but how would I merge H and I instead of excluding them? I get some errors when trying to merge other columns as well.

Comment: You can use nested `ifelse` for it. For example, `table(transform(set0, B = ifelse(B %in% c('F', 'G'), 'V', ifelse(B %in% c('H', 'I'), 'R', B))))` will merge `H` and `I` into `R`.